# Getting error in login of Server in SSMS Windows Authentication method ERROR: 18456

Tags: sql, ssms

So I created new user in my Laptop for some reasons and deleted the older local user,
So now when I try to connect to the server from SSMS It gives me the error for login error
what can I do now to use my old server as it has many important database of mine.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24306/gain-admin-access-to-sql-express-2008

Comment: you can reinstall MSSQL and attach those databases again

Comment: I tried performing the second method suggested in the recommended blog but I was not able to solve my problem @CaiusJard

Comment: Why were you not able to solve your problem?

Comment: Have you tried SQL Authentication with a SQL login? Are you a server administrator?